# Making a swiper for fetch Reddit posts

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, swiper.js, reddit

```js
const clientId = "CLIENT-ID";
const clientSecret = "CLIENT-SECRET";

async function fetchPosts() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/hot.json?limit=10"
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  
  // Exclude stickied posts
  const nonStickiedPosts = data.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.stickied);

  return nonStickiedPosts;
}

function filterValidPosts(posts) {
  return posts.filter(
    (post) =>
      post.data.title &&
      post.data.url &&
      post.data.url.startsWith("http") &&
      post.data.url.includes(".gif") &&
      post.data.url.includes("v.redd.it") &&
      post.data.self && // Exclude self-posts
      !post.data.removed // Exclude deleted posts
  );
}


function convertToDirectLink(redditMediaLink) {
    const url = new URL(redditMediaLink);

    // Check if it's a Reddit preview link
    if (url.hostname === "preview.redd.it") {
        const [mediaId, format] = url.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".");

        if (mediaId && format) {
            // Build the direct link
            return `https://i.redd.it/${mediaId}.${format}`;
        }
    }

    // If it's not a Reddit preview link, return the original link
    return redditMediaLink;
}

// ...

// Function to render posts as cards on the webpage
async function renderPosts(posts) {
  const container = document.getElementById("postsContainer");
  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i += 3) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    for (let j = i; j < i + 3 && j < posts.length; j++) {
      const post = posts[j];

      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.classList.add("card");
      const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
      cardContent.classList.add("card-content");

      if (post.data.is_gallery) {
        // Handle Reddit galleries
        if (post.data.media_metadata) {
          // Iterate over media_metadata to get direct links
          for (const mediaId in post.data.media_metadata) {
            const galleryImage = post.data.media_metadata[mediaId];
            const directLink = convertToDirectLink(galleryImage.s.u); // Use the s.u field for direct link
            const image = document.createElement("img");
            image.src = directLink;
            image.alt = post.data.title;
            cardContent.appendChild(image);
          }
        }
      } else if (post.data.url) {
        // Handle posts with a single image or external links
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = await convertToDirectLink(post.data.url);
        image.alt = post.data.title;
        cardContent.appendChild(image);
      }

      cardContent.innerHTML += `<h3>${post.data.title}</h3>`;
      card.appendChild(cardContent);
      row.appendChild(card);
    }

    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}




async function fetchAndRenderNewPosts() {
  try {
    const posts = await fetchPosts();
    const validPosts = filterValidPosts(posts);

    if (validPosts.length > 0) {
      renderPosts(validPosts);
    } else {
      console.warn("No valid posts fetched. Trying again with new posts.");
      const newPosts = await fetchPosts();
      renderPosts(newPosts);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching or rendering posts:", error);
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  fetchAndRenderNewPosts();

  setInterval(fetchAndRenderNewPosts, 300000); // Fetch new posts every 5 minutes (adjust as needed)
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-height: 100vh; /* Set a maximum height for the container */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scroll if needed */
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Adjust as needed for spacing between rows */
}

.card {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(33% - 20px); /* Adjust as needed for spacing between cards */
    max-width: 300px; /* Limit the maximum width of each card */

}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-content {
    position: relative;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; /* Ensure the image covers the entire container */
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="postsContainer"></div>
```

I made a Reddit post fetching web site and I'm able to get the galleries (posts with multiple images) in a card where all the images are put and also the single images posts as cards along with their title. Now for the gallery type posts, I want to make a swiper so that I can just swipe instead of seeing multiple images in a row in one card box, but I don't know how to do that.

```
function convertToDirectLink(redditMediaLink) {
    const url = new URL(redditMediaLink);

    // Check if it's a Reddit preview link
    if (url.hostname === "preview.redd.it") {
        const [mediaId, format] = url.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".");

        if (mediaId && format) {
            // Build the direct link
            return `https://i.redd.it/${mediaId}.${format}`;
        }
    }

    // If it's not a Reddit preview link, return the original link
    return redditMediaLink;
}

// ...

// Function to render posts as cards on the webpage
async function renderPosts(posts) {
  const container = document.getElementById("postsContainer");
  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i += 3) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    for (let j = i; j < i + 3 && j < posts.length; j++) {
      const post = posts[j];

      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.classList.add("card");
      const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
      cardContent.classList.add("card-content");

      if (post.data.is_gallery) {
        // Handle Reddit galleries
        if (post.data.media_metadata) {
          // Iterate over media_metadata to get direct links
          for (const mediaId in post.data.media_metadata) {
            const galleryImage = post.data.media_metadata[mediaId];
            const directLink = convertToDirectLink(galleryImage.s.u); // Use the s.u field for direct link
            const image = document.createElement("img");
            image.src = directLink;
            image.alt = post.data.title;
            cardContent.appendChild(image);
          }
        }
      } else if (post.data.url) {
        // Handle posts with a single image or external links
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = await convertToDirectLink(post.data.url);
        image.alt = post.data.title;
        cardContent.appendChild(image);
      }

      cardContent.innerHTML += `<h3>${post.data.title}</h3>`;
      card.appendChild(cardContent);
      row.appendChild(card);
    }

    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}

// ...



async function fetchAndRenderNewPosts() {
  try {
    const posts = await fetchPosts();
    const validPosts = filterValidPosts(posts);

    if (validPosts.length > 0) {
      renderPosts(validPosts);
    } else {
      console.warn("No valid posts fetched. Trying again with new posts.");
      const newPosts = await fetchPosts();
      renderPosts(newPosts);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching or rendering posts:", error);
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  fetchAndRenderNewPosts();

  setInterval(fetchAndRenderNewPosts, 300000); // Fetch new posts every 5 minutes (adjust as needed)
};
```

Code summary: this is everything I've done so far. The link converter converts the `preview.redd.it` link to `i.redd.it` for easier and high resolution displaying. The render part just renders the image in a card with 3 cards in each row.

Comment: "I want to make a swiper so that I can just swipe" - in the tags of your question, you mention swiper.js . Have you tried using that, since the [initialization](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#initialize-swiper) is missing from your code?

Comment: @FiddlingAway I've worked with swiper.js but only for 1 set of images. I don't really know how to set swiper.js for each card element that is containing more than 1 image.

Comment: This is just general advice - in the `if (post.data.is_gallery) {` part of your code, add a specific class to the galeries (for example `.postGallery`), and then go from there. Or, if youre unsure how to proceed, please create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/) in your question, and include relevant HTML (just populate it with what you would normally get when you fetch the data from reddit). We'll go from there.

Comment: @FiddlingAway here, I've added the snippet. The HTML is pretty simple of 1 line as you can see and i havent't included the scripts for swiper.js.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way of doing it.

```js
async function fetchPosts() {
  let data = {"kind":"Listing","data":{"children":[{"kind":"t3","data":{"subreddit":"memes","is_gallery":false,"title":"r/Memes is looking for new moderators! Interested? Fill out our application!","id":"18zq3y5","url":"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfBlrL6LVOktwIdGubvbJ7REeh9vANiBTIpUecW63PHINQECg/viewform","stickied":false}},{"kind":"t3","data":{"subreddit":"memes","is_gallery":false,"title":"It was the 9/one- one of British TV","id":"19c1wez","url":"https://i.redd.it/hoqa37i19sdc1.jpeg","stickied":false}},{"kind":"t3","data":{"subreddit":"McMansionHell","is_gallery":true,"title":"Look at the upper left corner of the bathroom","media_metadata":{"5j8l66lt27b61":{"s":{"y":576,"x":768,"u":"https://preview.redd.it/5j8l66lt27b61.jpg?width=768&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=ba0c95d8ce7cf1d325dfac2564c2fdd55b036508"},"id":"5j8l66lt27b61"},"797pwyft27b61":{"s":{"y":413,"x":550,"u":"https://preview.redd.it/797pwyft27b61.jpg?width=550&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=a6dc4d0e1fac886c901e662b08662c100a5ee4e7"},"id":"797pwyft27b61"},"pj9sc1st27b61":{"s":{"y":576,"x":768,"u":"https://preview.redd.it/pj9sc1st27b61.jpg?width=768&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=637aed513c30179864c5a33302f44bd035771e0b"},"id":"pj9sc1st27b61"}},"gallery_data":{"items":[{"media_id":"5j8l66lt27b61","id":22269281},{"media_id":"797pwyft27b61","id":22269279},{"media_id":"pj9sc1st27b61","id":22269284}]},"id":"kwudba","url":"https://www.reddit.com/gallery/kwudba","stickied":false}},{"kind":"t3","data":{"subreddit":"McMansionHell","is_gallery":true,"title":"This is a dummy gallery","media_metadata":{"f9gczent27b61":{"s":{"y":576,"x":768,"u":"https://preview.redd.it/f9gczent27b61.jpg?width=768&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=1a6cc9447c9b8bac8b5a91de7c8c32247d558eaa"},"id":"f9gczent27b61"},"v2fyorvt27b61":{"s":{"y":576,"x":768,"u":"https://preview.redd.it/v2fyorvt27b61.jpg?width=768&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=76fb9f6db49dd5a379eebd9a0ae7d3fa86c88745"},"id":"v2fyorvt27b61"}},"gallery_data":{"items":[{"media_id":"5j8l66lt27b61","id":22269281},{"media_id":"v2fyorvt27b61","id":22269285}]},"id":"dummygal","url":"https://www.reddit.com/gallery/dummygal","stickied":false}}],"before":null}};
    
    // Exclude stickied posts
    const nonStickiedPosts = data.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.stickied);
  
    return nonStickiedPosts;
}
  
function filterValidPosts(posts) {
    return posts.filter(
      (post) =>
        post.data.title &&
        post.data.url &&
        post.data.url.startsWith("http") &&
        post.data.url.includes(".gif") &&
        post.data.url.includes("v.redd.it") &&
        post.data.self && // Exclude self-posts
        !post.data.removed // Exclude deleted posts
    );
  }
  
  
function convertToDirectLink(redditMediaLink) {
  const url = new URL(redditMediaLink);

  // Check if it's a Reddit preview link
  if (url.hostname === "preview.redd.it") {
    const [mediaId, format] = url.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".");

    if (mediaId && format) {
      // Build the direct link
      return `https://i.redd.it/${mediaId}.${format}`;
    }
  }

  // If it's not a Reddit preview link, return the original link
  return redditMediaLink;
}

// ...

// Function to render posts as cards on the webpage
async function renderPosts(posts) {
  const container = document.getElementById("postsContainer");
  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i += 3) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    for (let j = i; j < i + 3 && j < posts.length; j++) {
      const post = posts[j];

      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.classList.add("card");
      const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
      cardContent.classList.add("card-content");

            let customClass = "";
      let swiperStart = `
        <!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
      `;
      let swiperContent = "";
      let swiperEnd = `
            </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
          <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        </div>
      `;
      if (post.data.is_gallery) {
        // Handle Reddit galleries
        if (post.data.media_metadata) {
            customClass = " gallery-post";
          // Iterate over media_metadata to get direct links
          for (const mediaId in post.data.media_metadata) {
            const galleryImage = post.data.media_metadata[mediaId];
            const directLink = convertToDirectLink(galleryImage.s.u); // Use the s.u field for direct link
            swiperContent += `
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img alt="`+post.data.title+`" src="`+directLink+`">
              </div>
            `;
          }
          
          const divElem = document.createElement("DIV");
          divElem.innerHTML = swiperStart + swiperContent + swiperEnd;
          cardContent.appendChild(divElem);
          cardContent.className += customClass;
        }
      } else if (post.data.url) {
        // Handle posts with a single image or external links
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = await convertToDirectLink(post.data.url);
        image.alt = post.data.title;
        cardContent.appendChild(image);
      }

      cardContent.innerHTML += `<h3>${post.data.title}</h3>`;
      card.appendChild(cardContent);
      row.appendChild(card);
    }

    container.appendChild(row);
  }
  
  initSwiper();
}
  
async function fetchAndRenderNewPosts() {
  try {
    const posts = await fetchPosts();
    const validPosts = filterValidPosts(posts);

    if (validPosts.length > 0) {
      renderPosts(validPosts);
    } else {
      console.warn("No valid posts fetched. Trying again with new posts.");
      const newPosts = await fetchPosts();
      renderPosts(newPosts);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching or rendering posts:", JSON.stringify(error));
  }
}
  
window.onload = function () {
  fetchAndRenderNewPosts();
};

function initSwiper() {
  if(document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-post").length > 0) {
    console.log("I'm in....");
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
      // Optional parameters
      direction: 'horizontal',
      loop: true,

      // If we need pagination
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },

      // Navigation arrows
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  } else {
    console.log("I'm not in :(");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-height: 100vh; /* Set a maximum height for the container */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scroll if needed */
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Adjust as needed for spacing between rows */
    min-width: 98vw;
}

.card {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(33% - 20px); /* Adjust as needed for spacing between cards */
    max-width: 300px; /* Limit the maximum width of each card */

}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-content {
    position: relative;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; /* Ensure the image covers the entire container */
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="postsContainer"></div>
```

---

**Changes made to your original code, for simplicity's sake**

You'll notice that I've removed your initial fetching logic. This was done for testing purposes - a greatly reduced JSON was used to mimic the response from your original URL.

Also, since they were not used in the available code, I've taken the liberty of removing the `clientId` and the `clientSecret` from the code. You will, of course, use them, if there's a need for it.

The `setInterval` has also been removed, as the code I'm providing is just for testing purposes - you will, of course, include it in your original code.

There were minor changes in the CSS, as well, to accommodate for the styling of the swiper (`min-width` was set for your `.row` class - remove it, and you'll see why it was added).

---

**Changes made to your original code, to include swiper.js**

The function `renderPosts` has been adapted to contain the logic for creating the swiper's container, which will hold the images retrieved from reddit. In doing this, I've relied on [the official documentation](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#add-swiper-html-layout). Please note that this is just one way of doing it - feel free to experiment, if you find that the solution I've offered is not suitable for what you need.

Adding a custom class to the cards containing galleries is done so that we'll know whether there's a need to initialize the swiper, or not.

Finally, at the very end of your `renderPosts` function, I've included a new function - `initSwiper`. The function is straightforward, and adapted from what is in [the official documentation](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#initialize-swiper) (no scrollbar, horizontal swiping, the swiper is initialized if there are gallery posts, etc).

Comment: Thank you a lot! That worked and now I think I'll work on keeping the posts that the code fetches. Thanks again you're a hero.